# makecell alters vertical alignment across table row

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, makecell

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}}
  \lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][2-4]\\
  \lipsum[1][5] & \makecell[l]{A\\B\\C\\D\\E}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

As can be seen, the use of `\makecell` altered the vertical alignment in the rest of the row. How to bring the vertical alignment of the affected row in harmony with the rest of the table (starting from top)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default for `\makecell` is `centred`, both vertically and horizontally. You could use `\makecell[lt]{A\\B\\C\\D\\E}`.

However, why use `\makecell` in a  `p`column type? You may as well use this code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\nl}{\newline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}}
  \lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][2-4]\\
  \lipsum[1][5] & A\nl B\nl C\nl D\nl E
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you have a dangling `}` in `C\nl D\nl E}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `\makecell` use `t` option:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}p{6cm}}
  \lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][2-4]\\
  \lipsum[1][5] & \makecell[tl]{A\\B\\C\\D\\E}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]